# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

XCode is driving me crazy (again). How do people use this?

```
-[UIViewController look_for_offer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e34220
2011-04-30 18:38:25.207 myApp[8261:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController look_for_offer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e34220'
```

Here's what I did. I made a button. I clicked on the button and went to the "connections" tab in the inspector. I dragged from the touch-down-event to the code and it automatically created an empty method and a method header. This is the method:

```
- (IBAction)look_for_offer:(id)sender {

}
```

Now remember, I didn't even write that. Interface Builder generated it for me. Yet when I build and click the button, I get the "unrecognized selector" error message.

It looks from the error message like he's trying to send the message look_for_offer to UIViewController. I don't know why he would do that. The method is in my view, which is a subclass of UIViewController:

```
@interface ClientSeekingView : UIViewController {

}

- (IBAction)look_for_offer:(id)sender;
```

I clearly dragged the action into that classes code, not into UIViewController. Why is he trying to send messages to UIViewController instead of my class?

What am I doing wrong? How do I please Xcode?

PS: I cleaned and rebuilt several times, doesn't help.

MrB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you didn't change the Interface Builder `File's Owner` object to your own class. IB has created an object of type `UIViewController`, not `ClientSeekingView`. The error message says that your selector is being sent to an object of class `UIViewController`.

To change the class, you would use the **Identity Inspector**.
[image: Identity Inspector Menu Item]

Comment: How do I change the "File's Owner"? There's a cube called "File's Owner" in the sidebar, but I can't seem to enter my class anywhere.

Comment: @MrB, I added a screenshot of the menu item to change the class name.