# Unrecognized selector sent to instance error from Utility App navigation controller view

Tags: ios, utility, mfmailcomposer

I have a utility app. I've implemented this code on the flipside, which calls a Feedback view to send an email, like this [tutorial](http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/using-apples-mail-composer/). This works, but then when I click on the Send Feedback UIButton, my app immediately crashes with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController sendMail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89c1960'.`

I've checked these things:

I've  declared the delegate properly and implemented it for the MailComposer.

My method, sendMail, is wired to the TouchUp Event for the button.

My method names agree:

```
- (IBAction)sendMail;
```

and

```
- (IBAction)sendMail 
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mfViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mfViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:mfViewController animated:YES];

}
else 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status:" message:@"Your phone is not currently configured to send mail." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

}

The code doesn't event get to this method because I have a breakpoint set at the top of the method implementation but doesn't get called. Nor did a breakpoint at ViewDidLoad get activated.

Looking at this error closely:

```
reason: '-[UIViewController sendMail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

it seems it is expecting a view controller named sendMail rather than a method.  I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843217/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) which seems very similar but I dont' see any other view controller names in the xib Identity drop down list. I think this is part of my problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Maybe I'm supposed to be presenting the MFMailComposer via a viewcontroller? If so, I'm not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incorrectly assigned the type `UIViewController` to your custom view-controller. You should select the class-type that actually applies to your custom view-controller (the one that holds the method implementation `sendMail`).

The problem with your code / setup is that your custom view controller gets instantiated with the type `UIViewController`. But, UIViewController does not implement any method called `sendMail`, hence you get an exception.

As you are not specifying the class name of your custom view controller, I will simply assume one for the sake for this answer; `MyCustomViewController`

Since you appear to use the InterfaceBuilder for setting those things up, use it to change the type of your view-controller towards `MyCustomViewController`.

[image]

EDIT

From your comments, I can see that you actually instantiate the view controller using code. In that case, replace your way with this:

```
MyCustomViewController *controller = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExMobSendFeedback" bundle:nil]; 
controller.title = @"Feedback"; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: Yes, I am using IB to set everything up. I don't see my viewcontroller name (XMSendMail) in the list of Custom Class classes in the on the Identity tab while I have my view highlighted.   Is there something else I'm supposed to do to get the viewcontroller listed there?   BTW, I created the XMSendMail viewcontroller by adding new files. Thanks

Comment: Just type it into the field named: Class under Custom Class.

Comment: That didn't work, it beeped and didn't accept the name. The viewcontroller is created programmtically via this:   UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExMobSendFeedback" bundle:nil];                                                            so maybe that's why it's not showing up in the class list. However, the files (.h, .m, .xib) do exist now. BTW, thanks for working with me on this.
    controller.title = @"Feedback";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: Ok progress. I took your modificaiton and changed it in the program and imported the header file for it and it produced no errors. However, I noticed that the viewcontroller name still didn't show up in the class list. That's when I noticed I didn't really have a viewcontroller in my list of objects in the xib, just the view and the button. So I added a viewcontroller, saw the ExMobSendMail name there and ran the app. It worked like a champ - Thanks Till for your help.