# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated not working on XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I have an XIB that I present as a modal view. I have a button that calls the following -

```
(IBAction)dismissVC:(id)sender {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

When I press it the app crashes with this notice -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController dismissVC:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8379350'
```

The thing I noticed is that I have a ViewController.xib file and I have this MapView.xib that is a modal VC I want to dismiss. It's presented from a ViewController.xib

What could be the possible issue? I've hooked up all the actions and the File Onwer thing as well.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the `MapView.h` file and everything above `@interface` in your `MapView.m` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843217/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

that might be your solution.

Comment: Tried this, it didn't help

Comment: I look up for you one moment

Comment: did you set the action in the header file?

Comment: Well, I just copy and paste it and in my try it worked fine?! :/

Comment: I have a question to you...!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20820/discussion-between-sergiusgee-and-noah-raissi)